# Sorting by element address

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

I stumbled across a situation where a library sorts a container (e.g. `std::vector<T>`) with a user-provided comparison object.  For one particular case, the user actually doesn't want to sort the container, but the sorting happens unconditionally.

So, to try to avoid this situation, I thought to try using a comparison object that sorts based on element address. Equivalently, we have:

```cpp
std::vector nums{1, 5, 4};
auto cmp = [](auto& a, auto& b) { return &a < &b; };
std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), cmp);
```

This "works" because `std::vector<T>` elements are stored in (contiguous) memory locations in the same order as the elements in the vector.  The end result is that the `nums` vector appears to have been left untouched even after sorting.

However, once I replace `std::vector<T>` with `std::array<T, N>`, I get a segmentation violation (see https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9srehdbhG).

My first thought is that I'm violating the type requirements as listed at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort:

> - `RandomIt` must meet the requirements of *ValueSwappable* and *LegacyRandomAccessIterator*.
> - The type of dereferenced `RandomIt` must meet the requirements of *MoveAssignable* and *MoveConstructible*.
> - `Compare` must meet the requirements of *Compare*.

My assumption was that the addresses of the elements would remain stable throughout the sort - this is almost certainly wrong.

So, which requirements/preconditions of `std::sort()` am I violating?

Comment: This seems to only happen with libstdc++. https://godbolt.org/z/Ya6zT7sbq

Comment: This does look like a compiler bug.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik happens only if `array` is a local variable, hmm. An odd optimization?

Comment: Ok, it's an odd bug related to that somehow clang uses 8-byte block aligned sort to sort _unaligned_  array (it is 12-byte long block). Forcing `long long` type upon `array` or moving `array` out of block solves the issue. The code is same in both cases, just location of array changes. I'm not sure, but I think it's still goes out of bounds in latter case.

Comment: **Congratulations**, I think you found a *bona fide* compiler bug!  Please file a bug report.  In the meantime, here's an alternative `cmp` that will get the job done: `auto cmp = [](auto&&, auto&&) { return false; };`

Comment: There are https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/algorithms#parallel.exec-3 and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/algorithms#parallel.user-1 which would make such a comparator UB, but it seems to me that both should apply to the parallel versions of the algorithms only, although that isn't obvious in the first case.

Comment: Bug reported at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111685

Comment: I think the problem is that, when using that comparator, your elements aren't swappable. If you swap them, the swapped elements don't appear to have each other's previous value from the perspective of the comparator.

Comment: @Eljay: That comparator's legal (all values are in a single equivalence class) but might need to be combined with `std::stable_sort` to actually guarantee the order is preserved.

Comment: Interestingly the paper that introduced the relevant restrictions for parallel algorithms considers the implications for potential use cases of address-based sorting, but it doesn't seem to indicate anywhere whether/how the (non-)application of these new restrictions on non-parallel versions of the algorithms should affect the use. See [P0518](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0518r1.html).

Comment: Is vs having the same bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `std::sort` isn't restricted to calling the comparator with references to elements of the specified range, it is also calling a comparison between a helper variable and an element of the range.

It's legal to take the address of that helper variable, but it's not legal to do a pointer comparison.

If you switch to `std::less()(&a, &b)` <strike>the segmentation fault goes away</strike> but it still is going to act really weird -- your comparator isn't invariant under copies.

This is a violation of [the concept required for sort compare functions](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#general-3):

> For algorithms other than those described in [alg.binary.search], comp shall induce a strict weak ordering on the values.

Note "ordering on the *values*", not "ordering on the *objects*".  That means you cannot rely on any properties of the objects being sorted (such as memory address) other than the value alone.

Comment: Ah.  Couldn't one then just cast the addresses to (e.g.) `unsigned long long`s and then compare the integers?  Incidentally, I still get the segfault if I do that.  (Yes, I realize this is icky, I'm just trying to understand where the illegal behavior creeps in.)

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel The problem is including the adresse in any way. When you move construct or move assign an element, the value should be transfered and shouldn't change. By using the adresse as the sorting predicate you basically include it as part of the value and breaking that expectation.

Comment: "_The problem is that std::sort isn't restricted to calling the comparator with references to elements of the specified range_": But where in the standard does it say that? `std::sort` is specified in terms of the postcondition + certain requirements. In OP's case the postcondition can be satisfied and it isn't obvious which of the requirements would be violated. If all requirements are satisfied, then an implementation ought to satisfy the postcondition and if using a temporary object makes this impossible, it shouldn't use one.

Comment: @user17732522: `&a < &b` is invalid if they aren't both subobjects of the same composite (array or parent object).  The `cmp` in the question is not a valid comparator because it places additional requirements on its arguments which are not part of the contract.

Comment: @BenVoigt "_which are not part of the contract_": Where is that specified?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#general

Comment: @BenVoigt The best I can see in there that would impose this contract is https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#general-3.sentence-3 because it uses the word "_values_". But that seems a bit vague.

Comment: @user17732522: The thing is that the contract for *Compare* doesn't limit the parameters.  Therefore the comparison function can't make assumptions about its parameters.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's not a reasonable interpretation. With the same reasoning `comp` would also be required to provide a strict weak ordering for any possible values that aren't part of the range.

Comment: @user17732522: You make it sound like it would be obviously wrong to require that, but I think it's quite reasonable.  For example, a pivoting sort (like quicksort) could choose the median value for its pivot, which can be a value not in the set.

Comment: @BenVoigt It is wrong to make this a requirement for `comp` rather than just using such a property for optimization where it is known to be true. Otherwise it is for example (on most implementations) impossible to use `std::less<>` for `Compare` (or the overload without `Compare`) on floating point values. It is then also impossible to use `std::less<>` (or the overload without `Compare`) for pointers, even if the intention is to only sort pointers pointing into the same (external) array.

Comment: @user17732522: The Standard doesn't agree with you.  The comparator function is required to model the concept (in context at the call-site, which refers to what template specializations are found, and not to the actual arguments passed to `sort()`).  A comparator which only adheres to the requirements for a subset of possible arguments is not modeling the concept as required.  https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.requirements

Comment: @BenVoigt `Compare` isn't required to satisfy any concept anywhere, hence it also can't be required to model any.

Answer (score 2):

I think your use is valid according to the current standard draft.

`std::sort` is specified in [[alg.sort]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sort-3) via its effects on the passed iterator sequence (not copies). The state required as postcondition is achievable and already satisfied when `std::sort` is entered.

The only potentially relevant requirement I see is that in [[alg.sorting.general]/3 sentence 3](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting.general#3.sentence-3), which vaguely requires `comp` to be a strict weak order on "*the values*". It doesn't specify what values are meant (or what qualifies as the value in relation to the iterators). But given that the binary predicate properties as well as the sorting postcondition are established only on iterators, the only reasonable interpretation I have is that it also considers only passing dereferenced iterators (into the iterator sequence passed to the sorting algorithm).

Then the implementation would not be allowed to use a local copy of elements to apply `comp` to. `std::sort` can be implemented without that.

Furthermore, [[algorithms.parallel.user]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/algorithms#parallel.user-1) and [[algorithms.parallel.exec]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/algorithms#parallel.exec-3) specifically add requirements that would allow implementations to work on object copies instead, but only for *parallel algorithms* (i.e. the overloads with *ExecutionPolicy* template parameters). These wouldn't be necessary if the `Compare` requirements would permit this generally.

(In case of [[algorithms.parallel.user]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/algorithms#parallel.user-1) it doesn't specifically say that it applies only to parallel algorithms, but I am inferring that from the context. I might be mistaken here and this is intended to *always* apply. But then I would expect it to be moved to a different part of the standard.)

The paper [P0518](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0518r1.html) that made these additions based on a NB comment also seems to consider only parallel algorithms. I am not sure whether denying the use of local copies in the non-parallel variants of the algorithms is reasonable, but given that the paper didn't consider them as well, it seems to me that the committee members intentionally put more restrictions on the implementation for the non-parallel cases (or this specific use was overlooked).

Comment: libstd++ issue https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111685 is currently closed as Invalid

Comment: Closed by the issue submitter, so that doesn't mean GCC maintainers have closed it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, does it mean that if for example I submit the same issue again, it will be fixed in libstdc++?

Comment: Please don't resubmit the same thing again, it will be closed as a duplicate. If you want something to be reconsidered, use the existing report.

Comment: @Fedor (Notifying you about the comment above.)

Answer (score 1):

Since your comparator doesn't describe a strict weak ordering, it is [invalid for use with `std::sort`](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#general-3.sentence-3). Passing such a comparator to `std::sort` is undefined behavior as far as I understand, meaning that both a crash and it working perfectly fine are valid outcomes.

Elements are moved inside the array during sorting, and thus can change address. `std::sort` assumes that a < b still holds even after a and b have been moved around, which is not the case when using your comparator.

I believe that what is happening here is that the invalid comparator is causing `std::sort` to run outside of the provided range. When using `vector` it just stomps over the heap without causing much damage, but when using `array` it trashes the stack, causing the crash. [Moving the array to the heap prevents the crash](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1jj4Y7951)

Comment: Long ago, I remember reading one of the programming magazines (probably Dr. Dobbs Journal, although it might even have been before that) talking about making loops run faster, and it pointed out that most loops have two stopping conditions (finding what it searches for, and reaching the end of the data), but that checking for the end of the data is not actually essential.  If one can add a "bookend" item that always matches the other exit condition, then one saves a comparison and conditional branch on every iteration, which might have been as much as 20-30% of the loop body.

Comment: I believe that this optimization technique is in play in the particular standard library implementation encountered by OP.